# Freemarker - How to access value in array that's been passed in?

Tags: java, freemarker

So I'll have an array passed into my .ftl file from Java:

```
images = [logourl, bannerurl]
```

Say `logourl` and `bannerurl` are both strings, leading to the image URL path stored somewhere on a server. How would I access this string value?

```
<img src=${images.logourl} />
```

or

```
<img src=${logourl} />
```

or

```
<img src=${images[0]} />
```

or something else?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a index to get at an item like `${images[i]}`:

```
<img src="${images[0]}"/>
```

Comment: Thanks! I'll be sure to test it out.

Comment: Wait; are you sure that it's correct to put the `${}` inside quotes? What if `images[0]` is already a string? Would you not include quotes?

Comment: yes, it is correct to put inside quotes. See the template and output example in http://freemarker.org/docs/dgui_quickstart_basics.html

Comment: Sorry to bother you again; if I have an object (`companyInfo = {name, addr, tel}`), how would I access the name? `${companyInfo.name}`?

Comment: Yes. Note that you need to provide `getter` in your class such that Freemarker can find them. Details please check http://freemarker.org/docs/pgui_quickstart_createdatamodel.html.